# How to do a mail merge from a SP List to a word doc?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a simple way to do this?  Basically I would have a list that contains a bunch of customer information and I would like to merge each list item to a specific word doc and insert each document into a library.

I've found a few things online but they seem unnecessarily complex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the list to an Excel Spreadsheet, save it out on your PC somewhere, then merge using that.

I think you can save out the individual documents created from a merge, but that'd be a feature of Word itself, not sure if it does that out the box, might need a macro.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to use a SPList as such, but I once did a spike where the metadata from a SharePoint document library should be inserted into a number of quick parts in a Word document.

Since the event triggers on a SPList is not triggered until the document is saved (Adding/Added) the quick parts could not be populated when the document was created, at least not using the event trigger approach.

I then switched to a VSTO approach and then is was possible to populate the tags right away, but it required a lot of code to fetch the metadata using a SharePoint web service, and the deployment story using VSTO was a nightmare, so the project is currently in hibernation.

Answer (score -1):

try our mail merge web part at http://sharepoint.linkconcepts.co.uk

we also offer 15 day evaluation trial to test on your own server

Regards
John

Comment: Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines on what is acceptable. If you just post an ad for your product you will probably get down-voted by the community.